# Should I ground a canless recessed LED light?

Tags: electrical

I replaced two old lights, in a junction boxes, with a canless option.

[image: box]

It has multiple install options; I wanted wired.

[image: stuff]

The directions don't show grounding the bracket.

[image: manual]

I put a nut on the grounds and put them back up into the box.

But shouldn't it have been grounded to the bracket or are these LEDs a special case?

EDIT:
A better photo:

[image]

Comment: Yes these LEDs look like a special case, and that case appears to be plastic. How would you possibly ground plastic?

Comment: Are they UL certified? Are they certified from another NRTL? It’s possible they are not NRTL certified.

Comment: Also from the photo, I see that the light has a metal bracket that is screwed to the junction box. That metal bracket should be grounded. Even plastic junction boxes have a metal ground strap that connects to the device screw’s post. This does not look right.

Comment: The top image in step 2A of the instructions looks like this can be used as a retrofit into a screw in Edison bulb base. That wouldn't be grounded, either. Additionally, I've installed porcelain (and plastic) simple Edison bulb bases that are decidedly _not_ grounded and have zero provision for attaching a ground wire. These were sold in retail outlets in the 90s (probably Leviton brand) and were definitely UL certified. Lights often aren't grounded.

Comment: @FreeMan if it were all plastic or all porcelain, I would agree with you. I have a porcelain bulb base in my closet right now. But this isn’t that and I see plenty of metal coming out of the plastic light. I would double check everything to ensure that the light is NRTL certified and that the large metal mounting plate is grounded.